# Unable to set zIndex fro autocomplete in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project where i have to implement a search bar which should be in my header component , when ever i try to search the search is working fine but at the same time the search options are overlapping the my content below it. how can i resolve this? 
[image]

I tried adding zIndex both using css and noraml jsx way both dint work for me bellow is my code.
Header.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';
import { getStocks, matchStocks } from './data';


class Header extends Component {
  state = { value: '' };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 0, marginLeft: 0 }}>
        <div className="callout primary" id="Header">
        
        <div className="row column">
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
            <div style={{ zIndex: 10 }}> // this is where i am trying to set the zIndex
              
            <Autocomplete
          classNames={{ autocompleteContainer: 'ac-container' }}
          value={ this.state.value }
          inputProps={{ id: 'states-autocomplete' }}
          wrapperStyle={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-block' }}
          items={ getStocks() }
          getItemValue={ item => item.name }
          shouldItemRender={ matchStocks }
          onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value }) }
          onSelect={ value => this.setState({ value }) }
          renderMenu={ children => (
            <div className = "menu">
              { children }
            </div>
          )}
          renderItem={ (item, isHighlighted) => (
            <div
              className={`item ${isHighlighted ? 'item-highlighted' : ''}`}
              key={ item.abbr } >
              { item.name }
            </div>
          )}
              />

              
              </div>
        </div>

        
      </div>
         
       
      </div>
      


    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?